# How to set the activity indicator in the navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, frame, activity-indicator, navigationbar

I am new to iphone development. I want to set an activity indicator in the navigation bar. I see my activity indicator below the navigation bar. My code is here

```
- (IBAction) gomethod : (id) sender {
    xxMapSubviewcontroller = [[XxMapSubviewcontroller alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:xxMapSubviewcontroller animated:YES];

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0);
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [xxMapSubviewcontroller.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
}
```

How can i set my activity indicator in the navigation bar? Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I add the below piece of code in the view where i wanted the activity indicator in the navigation bar.

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
[self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: I noticed that on iOS 7 you need to use `activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];` or the indicator will not appear.

Answer (score 30):

Swift Code:

```swift
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(barButton, animated: true)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me in Swift:

```
let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
let refreshBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshBarButton
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Comment: This crashes in 10.1.1  with:  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Works on 11.4 without any issues.

Answer (score 13):

You are creating a new activity indicator view here, which is fine, but you are not referring to the activity indicator in the status bar.

To show the activity indicator in the status bar, simply call this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

Comment: I want to display the activity indicator in the navigation bar

Comment: I needed Warrior's solution because I am hiding the status bar. Not that there's anything wrong with your solution of course!

Answer (score 5):

**On storyboard:** Create `BarButtonItem` at the navigation bar.
Add View to be son of your `BarButtonItem` and `ActivityIndicator` to be son of your `View`.

Comment: Yes, on StoryBoard: drag to navigation bar the BarButtonItem, now drag the UIView to be subview of BarButtonItem, now drag the ActivityIndicator to be subview of the UIView.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift**

1. Connect `UIBarButtonItem` from `storyboard` to `yourViewController`
2. remove `week` from its definition like: `@IBOutlet var btNavigaitonRight: UIBarButtonItem!`
3. Use these methods for start and stopping activity indicator:

   ```
   var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

   func startBarButtonIndicator() {
       activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
       activityIndicator?.color = .gray
       let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator!)
       self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(barButton, animated: true)
       activityIndicator?.startAnimating()
   }

   func stopBarButtonIndicator() {
       activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
       navigationItem.setRightBarButton(btNavigaitonRight, animated: true)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Like WhatsApp:

//Declare

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
```

//ViewDidLoad

```
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

func showIndicator() {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.activityIndicator
    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
}

func hideIndicator() {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! My indicator is working now.

I am sharing a code example for fellow noobs, to put this in context.

**- (void)viewDidLoad**

```
// custom button images
UIImage *customImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu24"];
UIImage *customImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search24"];
UIImage *customImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back24"];

// These are linked in my story board to Navigation Item
[self customiseBarBtnItem:[self menu_button] 
    customImage:customImage selector:@selector(menuPressed:)];
[self customiseBarBtnItem:[self search_button] 
    customImage:customImage2 selector:@selector(searchPressed:)];
[self customiseBarBtnItem:[self backButton] 
    customImage:customImage3 selector:@selector(backPressed:)];

//initialize the activity indicator - as @antf comment suggests for ios7   
UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]                                      
     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

//store it as a property on the view controller
self.activityIndicator = actInd;

// this sets up activity indicator    
UIBarButtonItem *progress_indicator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
     initWithCustomView:[self activityIndicator]];

// link custom buttons AND activity indicator in desired order to navigation bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         self.menu_button,
         self.search_button, 
         progress_indicator, 
         nil];
```

**// For completeness - this is how I programmatically show/hide my back button**

```
if ( bShowBack == YES ) 
     self.navItemBar.leftBarButtonItem = self.backButton;
else 
     self.navItemBar.leftBarButtonItem = Nil;
```

**// I use my activity indicator with a UIWebView so trigger it as follows**

```
  - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
  {    
    [[self activityIndicator] startAnimating];
  }

  - (void)didFailLoadWithError:(UIWebView *)webView 
          didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
  {    
     [[self activityIndicator] stopAnimating];
  }

  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webView
  {
     [[self activityIndicator] stopAnimating];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, I did the following:

**Enable:** `UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true`

**Disable:** `UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false`

Comment: This goes into the status bar though

Comment: You're not wrong. I mis-read the OP - apologies. Having said that, I came across this post searching for an answer of how to solve the problem of showing the network activity indicator in the status bar - hopefully my answer will still provide some help to someone, if not to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question with response here:
[iphone - programatically change navigation bar button to activity indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249363/iphone-programatically-change-navigation-bar-button-to-activity-indicator)

I wanted to change the refresh button in the nav bar to the activity indicator and back again.

Answer (score 1):

try this : `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView = your_view`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use it now and the code mentioned by warrior didn't work exactly as is. I had to change the initialization of activityIndicator:

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

With this change it should work as expected.